# How to send commands to USB line printer in Java

Tags: java, linux, printing

I need to print some stuff via a thermal printer SK-21. I want to send command to control linefeed etc. I've written a simple test code to print a line and to eject the papier by command 0D. There's the piece of code it's just simple primitive for test:

```
FileOutputStream printer = new FileOutputStream("/dev/usb/lp0");
String text = "This is a test print performed by my application";
printer.write(text.getBytes());
printer.write(0x0D);
printer.flush();
printer.close();
```

It prints the text, but doesn't react at all to the command 0x0D which should eject the printed line. I have to eject the paper manually by pressing a button. If I do the following commands in terminal:

```
echo "text" >> lp0
echo -e \\x0d >> lp0
```

It prints "text" and ejects paper with printed line.

Any ideas how to do it in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Your "echo" commands send a trailing `\n`  each, which is code `0x0A`.

Try the following:

```
printer.write(0x0D);
printer.write(0x0A);
```